# I only want a div to display on screen depending on a boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I only want a particular `div` to display if `showHideClassName` is set to the value of `true`. I have this code in my React application so that a div will either display or not depending on the status of `showHideClassName`:

```
render() {
    ...
    const showHideClassName = showPrompt ? 'show-div' : 'display-none';
        return (
            <div className={showHideClassName}>
                ...
            </div>
        );
}
```

The div is always visible though. Is there any way I can get this to work as I desire?

Comment: What do the classes `show-div` and `display-none` do? Where are they defined?

Comment: What is ```showPrompt``` ? is it a state or props ?? and when does it change the value from either true /false ?

Comment: Learn to use your browser's debugging tools. Is the right class assigned to the div? If yes, the problem is with your CSS rules. If not, it's with your JavaScript code.

Comment: Was in the middle of updating my question with some extra info when I realised I don't have `display-none` in my css. Now that I've added ```
 .display-none {
    display: none;
  }``` it works as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `display-none` in my css. Now that I've added the below, it works ad desired.

```css
.display-none { display: none; }
```